# Consultar EN Agrupaciones

Tags: sql-server

Buenas miren tengo aqui una duda , pues tengo una Tabla Empleado y una Tabla Venta , y en venta tengo tipos de documentos(Boleta Factura,etc), entonces la consulta que quiero hacer en Sql Server 2014 es que me liste los empleados y me muestre  el numero que a emitido dicho empleado de cada tipo de documento y asi mismo sus respectivos montos totales.
Por ejemplo:
empleado A emitio 2 facturas  250.00 
           emitio 3 boletas    300.00
empleado B emitio 5 facturas   1000.00
           emitio 1 boleta     200.00

Nose si se podra hacer, si me ayudar porfavor.

Comment: Para saber si se puede o no necesitamos, un ejemplo de los datos, la estructura de la tabla y lo que probaste hasta ahora. mira por favor el [tour] y [ask]

Answer (score 1):

la proxima vez publica las consultas que has intentado hacer, asi por lo menos tendríamos los nombres de los campos y las tablas, pero bueno te digo mas o menos como sería (inventando los nombres de los campos claro)

```
 SELECT E.EMPLEADO, COUNT(V.*) CANTIDAD, SUM(TOTAL) MONTO
 FROM EMPLEADOS E
 INNER JOIN VENTA V ON V.EMPLEADO = E.EMPLEADO
 GROUP BY E.EMPLEADO
```

Si no logras armar tu consulta muestra los intentos que has hecho y asi se te ayuda mejor.

Saludos!